# How strong is an on-hit dispel effect?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, monster-design

I am considering customising a monster that can make a dispel magic check (as the *dispel magic* spell in area use, but only affect the one it hits, CL=10) every time it hits someone. Normally at what level should a group of PC be able to handle this kind of effect?

Considering this monster can attack 4 times per round. I haven't decided it's AB yet but it would likely be a CR 14-ish monster (so probably +22-ish). I am asking this because I see there's no similar example (at least nothing I am aware of) in MM. The closest hits are those with at-will spell-like abilities of *dispel magic* / *greater dispel magic*, which they can do at most once per round.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Pretty strong

Assuming 4 hits on an opponent buffed by CL 14 (as per your proposed CR 14) support spells, each of those support spells will have a chance of approximately 68% of being dispelled each round.

This will bring a buffed fighter or even a CoDzilla down to earth pretty quickly, especially if the monster has some way to reach flying opponents.

Against a party below level 14, or at least one relying on a primary buffer with CL below 14, I'd call it lethal, at least if the monster has the capabilities (or allies) to take advantage of the weakened PCs.

It will certainly eat through buffs and force the expenditure of resources like nobody's business.

#### The Spellgaunt is not really close, but sort of?

The Spellgaunt has a potentially nasty pair of abilities:

> **Disjunctive Bite (Su)**: A magic item bitten by a spellgaunt (see Attacking an Object in Chapter 8 of the Player's Handbook), must make a successful (DC 23) or instantly become a non-magical object. A spellgaunt feeding on an artifact has a 33% chance of destroying the item. If it destroys the item it must make a successful save (DC 25) or die instantly from an overwhelming ingestion of magical energy.
>
> *A spellcaster or a creature with supernatural or spell-like abilities that is bitten by a spellgaunt must make a Fortitude save (DC 23) or lose the ability to cast spells or use its magical abilities for 1d2 rounds.*
>
> **Snatch Item (Ex)**: A spellgaunt can take an openly displayed magic item away from an
> opponent with a successful disarm attempt, whether or not the item is
> actually a weapon. It cannot remove armor items that are attached at
> multiple locations, but it can snatch forcefully enough to break a
> single strap or other such attachment - the strap holding a wand to an
> opponent's belt, for example.

The Spellgaunt also has SR 35, DR 15/magic and permanent Detect Magic. And is CR 12.

#### Bad ideas, don't listen to me

Give your monster [Phase Spider](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/phaseSpider.htm)-like **Ethereal Jaunt** and Spellgaunt-like **permanent Detect Magic** and a **Disjunctive Bite** to go with the four Claw attacks, and have it bypass the front-line in favor of the casters. A Wizard's not so hot without Mage Armor, Fly and Resilient Sphere.

<del>Also give it levels in Beholder Mage, because everything's better with levels in Beholder Mage.</del>